# How to skip Windows Server 2012 "Scanning and repairing drive" on startup?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

is there a way to skip "Scanning and repairing drive" (different than "C:") on Windows Server 2012 startup? In previous Windows systems this could be done by pressing any key during startup when Windows tried to fix problematic drive but I don't see any option in Windows Server 2012.

Regards